# Linux bc command total counts

Tags: linux, bash, bc

Here is the output of my netstat command. I want to count total of first field number like `7+8+1+1+1+1+3+1+2..so on...` How do i use `bc` or any other method command to total count them?

```
[root@example httpd]# netstat -natp | grep 7143 | grep EST | awk -F' ' '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -nr | uniq -c
      7 209.139.35.xxx
      8 209.139.35.xxx
      1 209.139.35.xxx
      1 209.139.35.xxx
      1 208.46.149.xxx
      3 96.17.177.xxx
      1 96.17.177.xxx
      2 96.17.177.xxx
```

Comment: you probably have a better chance of getting an answer on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the first column with awk  (You don't actually need this, but I'm leaving it as a monument to my eternal shame)

```
awk {'print $1'}
```

and then use awk again to sum the column of numbers and print the result

```
awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

All together:

```
netstat -natp | grep 7143 | grep EST | awk -F' ' '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -nr | uniq -c | awk {'print $1'}  | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

I know this doesn't use bc, but it gets the job done, so hopefully that's enough.

Comment: Actually you don't need to do `awk '{print $1}'` first.

Comment: Gah!  You're right of course.  As I was building it up on the command line I was trying to use bc (and gave up) but the print $1 got left over.